# How to delete an element whilst looping through the array

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, java-stream

I have an object that contains a list of other objects which contains another list of objects. Much like a DTO.
Within those objects, there's a list of another type of object in which I would like to remove that element if the object contains a specific String.

E.g.

```
CustomerDTO customerDTO = CustomerTransformer.transformCustomer(custom);
List<InfoDTO> info = customerDTO.getInfo();
info(infoDTO -> {
    List<MoreDTO> d = infoDTO.getMore();
    for (MoreDTO moreDTO : d) {
        List<ChannelDTO> channels = MoreDTO.getChannels();
        for (ChannelDTO cdto : contentChannels) {
            if ("apple".equals(cdto.getId())) {
                moreDTO.getChannels().remove(cdto);
            }
        }
    }

});
```

But that really doesn't seem efficient and there might be a possible change of a null pointer? Is there a better way of writing it? And would using streams and using the filter in streams help?

I'm new to Java.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-

Comment: It's not about efficiency, it's about correctness. Your code would fail with a ConcurrentModificationException. You really need to test your code before making assumptions.

Comment: I guess you need to use an `Iterator` for that.

Comment: Check my answer, let me know if you need help

Answer (score 3):

You cannot remove elements from your list while iterating/looping it, there will be a `ConcurrentModificationException`

So to avoid that, you can use Java 8 Filter here, in this way -

```
contentChannels = contentChannels
 .stream()
 .filter(cdto->(!"apple".equals(cdto.getId())))
 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Another option is using `removeIf()`

Comment: filtering and creating a new list is completely different from removing an element from a list.

Comment: Agreed, in that case `removeIf()` will be a better idea

Comment: I don’t think that the obsolete brackets improve readability. Further, care to use `"apple"` instead of `“apple”` in source code.

Answer (score 2):

The above code will not work please refer to @JB Nizet comment,

[Triggering a ConcurrentModificationException](https://www.baeldung.com/java-concurrentmodificationexception)

> Essentially, the ConcurrentModificationException is used to fail-fast when something we are iterating on is modified. Let’s prove this with a simple test:

```
List<Integer> integers = newArrayList(1, 2, 3);

for (Integer integer : integers) {
    integers.remove(1);
}
```

So you can use `forEach`and `removeIf` to avoid `ConcurrentModificationException`

```
List<InfoDTO> info = customerDTO.getInfo();
info.forEach(more->more.getMore().forEach(channelDto->channelDto.getChannels().removeIf(cdto->"apple".equals(cdto.getId()))));
```

Or if you have only `List<ChannelDTO>`

```
List<ChannelDTO> channels = MoreDTO.getChannels();
channels.removeIf(cdto->"apple".equals(cdto.getId()));
```

Comment: A simple test should not rely on an unspecified 3rd party library. There is no `newArrayList` in the standard Java API. Further, using a `List<Integer>` is a bad example. Readers are tempted into thinking that this code was removing the element `1`, when it actually removes element `2`, at *index* `1`. Perhaps, you rather meant `integers.remove(integer);`, to be closer to the OP’s code.